# Python package to manage module system in HPCs

Tags: python, module, environment, hpc

I'm working in an HPC environment which uses the [module system](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) for software-version management. I'm using python for the automation of the installation of a certain software which requires some dependencies.

Do you know if there exists any python package/module to manage the module system? (list available modules, load/unload modules, read modulefiles, etc). I could'n find anything similar.

Comment: I am not aware of any Python interface to the module system. How about you be the first one to create such and make it open source? It should be fairly easy to parse the terse output from `module -t <cmd>`.

Comment: Hi Hristo. Yes I think that that's what I'll do, as I was not able to find anything similar and I think It may be useful. I'll post again when I have something or when I arrive to an already implemented solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at  [easybuild](http://hpcugent.github.io/easybuild/). It's designed to automate the installation of scientific software and it handles modulefiles so you might be able to find interesting patterns/clues in there.